# CBC DES with pycrypto

Tags: python, pycrypto

I'm trying to better understand how to work with the crypto libraries in Python and I'm stuck on what seems to be an incredibly simple DES encrypt/decrypt using CBC

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
obj=DES.new('abcdefgh', DES.MODE_CBC, '12345678')
plain='hellohello'
ciph=obj.encrypt(plain + "XXXXXX")
print(ciph)
print(obj.decrypt(ciph))
```

While using ECB, the above works easily, but with CBC, the output scrambles the first 8 char block.

The output here is:

```
b'{\x03\x1ca\xe3e\xa2\xd4<DEh\x10 \xf63'
b'e\x13\x1a0J~\xa4gloXXXXXX'
```

I don't see this in the documentation for pycrypto, but I admit, I've not pored over it exhaustively.

Why does the first block get scrambled like this?

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the problem.... this also happens with AES CBC.  The object maintains the state of the CBC feedback and would use it instead of the IV for the first block.  It would be set to the last value of the encryption operation.

Subsequent blocks are XORed with the ciphertext so come out clear, meaning only the first block is scrambled.

Creating a new object fixes it:

```
>>> obj=DES.new('abcdefgh', DES.MODE_CBC, '12345678')
>>> obj.decrypt(ciph)
b'hellohelloXXXXXX'
```